# How to increase memory of a jnlp file?

Tags: out-of-memory, 32bit-64bit, heap-memory, java-web-start, jnlp

I had created a jnlp file and specified max-heap size as 4096m. After downloading the jnlp file, I cross-checked the memory parameters and max-heap size of 4096m was getting reflected over there. But when I tried to run the jnlp file, it was not able to load a particular dataset(which was around 2GB). It was throwing an out-of-memory error in the console. From the task manager, I got to know that the application was not using more than 1.2 GB, even though 4 GB is specified.

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit OS and Java 8.

Can someone please help me here?

Note: I have passed -Xmx4096m as runtime parameter for java in the control panel as well.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit or 32-bit JVM?

Comment: I'm using 64-bit JVM

Comment: Then it's a bit strange, 1.2GB is a sounds much like the maximum reachable heapsize in a 32-bit process. Could you please also share the exact error-type? OutOfMemoryError has various flavours with totally different possible causes.

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a href attribute in the jnlp file header, which was overriding the configuration values present in the current jnlp. After removing that reference, it's working as expected.